# Is there a way to log in to discord using a python script?

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

My goal is to be able to loging to Discord using a script and then be able to send messages to channels. I need it to communicate with a music bot automatically but if I write a bot for discord other bot's will ignore it so thats not an option. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you not to pursue this goal further, as it is a violation of the [Discord Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/terms) and is illegal.
Probably your account will be terminated by Discord as a result.

If you want to automate Discord Bots you can take it into consideration to code your own.

Comment: Oh I didn't relise it was against their terms of service. i guese I have to  create my own music bot.